# Group Duplicate Items with Linq while adding totals

Tags: c#, linq

I have this application I am trying to add functionality to. This function returns a List.

*EDIT:*
The functionality is to collate all the costs per grade group for the whole company. However the result shows the cost for each companies grade groups. Meaning there is duplicate GradeGroupCodes because those grade groups belong to a different child company. I want to take all of those results and then sum them all together so ALL childs companies totals are totaled inside one gradegroup.

i.e
Magnesium 1,000 
Magneisum 500 
Magnesium 1,500

I want 
Magnesium 3,000

I am trying to use a Linq query to add together the totals of duplicate "GradeGroupCodes" into one.

```
return summaryResults.GroupBy(name => name.GradeGroupCode).Select(item => item.First()).ToList();
```

I used the `.Select(.First())` in an attempt to have it return a List rather than a IGrouping<>.

I understand it doesn't work because it is just returning the first item that had a duplicate GradeGroupCode, however I have been fiddling with this for more than 3 hours and can't seem to figure out how to get the Duplicate GradeGroupCodes to collapse into each other while summing their totals.

I would like to do this in LINQ but if it isn't possible I guess I could try a different way.

*Added for clarity*

Summary results is just s list of this object

```
var summaryLine = new AvgCostSummary
{
   GradeGroupCode = avgCostQuery.GradeGroupCode.Trim(),
   Grade = firstOrDefault.Grade.Trim(),
   QtyRecNt = firstOrDefault.QtyRecNt,
   AvgCostDl = firstOrDefault.AvgCostDl,
   AvgPricePerLb = firstOrDefault.AvgPricePerLb,
   TotalCost = firstOrDefault.TotalCost,
   Discount = firstOrDefault.Discount,
   ConsNum = avgCostQuery.ConsNum,
   PeriodBegin = avgCostQuery.PeriodBegin,
   PeriodEnd = avgCostQuery.PeriodEnd
};
```

In this particular instance ConsNum is of no consideration, it will not be displayed.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: What you mean by [duplicate "GradeGroups"]?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear. Basically since this returns results for all the child companies there will be for example multiple instances of one gradegroupcode because multiple companies have totals for that gradegroup. I would like to collapse all of those into one, while totaling the numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand you well, but... If you want to get result per company in group, why don't you use `GroupBy` twice: first -  for company, second - for GradeGroup?

Comment: Just the GradeGroups not the companies. This is a parent company with tens of children companies. They share gradegroups in a majority of instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Michal Turczyn for sending me down the right path.

There were other properties I needed to use than the ones provided, but that didn't change the solution.

A combination of my original attempted solution and Michal's was the ticket.

```
  // Group the results
           var groupedResult = summaryResults.GroupBy(name => name.GradeGroupCode);

           // Calculate the correct totals for the groups and assign them to the first item in the group
            foreach (var group in groupedResult)
            {
                group.First().QtyOrderedSummary     = group.Sum(QtyOrderedSummary => QtyOrderedSummary.QtyOrderedSummary);
                group.First().QtyShippedSummary     = group.Sum(QtyShippedSummary => QtyShippedSummary.QtyShippedSummary);
                group.First().QtyReceivedSummary    = group.Sum(QtyReceivedSummary => QtyReceivedSummary.QtyReceivedSummary);
                group.First().QtyDueSummary         = group.Sum(QtyDueSummary => QtyDueSummary.QtyDueSummary);
                group.First().CostSummary           = group.Average(CostSummary => CostSummary.CostSummary);
                group.First().TotalCostSummary      = group.Sum(TotalCostSummary => TotalCostSummary.TotalCostSummary);
            }

            // Return the first items of the group to a list
            return groupedResult.Select(item => item.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: This is very bad solution due to many `First()` calls.

Comment: How would you have done it different? I'm always ready to learn how to be more efficient.

Comment: If you're able to create sample data (dummy data) and expected output, i'll show you the way...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest below LINQ query (comments in code).

```
summaryResults
    .GroupBy(name => name.GradeGroupCode)
    .Select(group =>
    {
        var firstItem = group.First();
        return new AvgCostSummary()
        {
            // For all properties I use data from first result,
            // as you did not specify otherwise, except TotalCost
            // which I assume we ned to sum.
            GradeGroupCode = firstItem.GradeGroupCode.Trim(),
            Grade = firstItem.Grade.Trim(),
            QtyRecNt = firstItem.QtyRecNt,
            AvgCostDl = firstItem.AvgCostDl,
            AvgPricePerLb = firstItem.AvgPricePerLb,
            
            // Here we use whole group to sum TotalCost
            TotalCost = group.Sum(item => item.TotalCost), 
            
            Discount = firstItem.Discount,
            ConsNum = firstItem.ConsNum,
            PeriodBegin = firstItem.PeriodBegin,
            PeriodEnd = firstItem.PeriodEnd
        }
    });
```

Caution: it will flatten your data and in place of each unique group code there will be JUST ONE object with summed totals.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for that, added small optimization regarding that :)

Comment: Arrg! you just made me realize I wil need to calculate a new AvgCostDL and AvgPricePerLb for each group after I collapse them.

Comment: @AdamSchneider It should be easy to do in that lambda in `Select` method - you have whole group at your disposal :) If answer solved your problem please accept it by marking green check on the left side (and optionally upvote)

Comment: If this flattens my data this wont work. I still need each Unique Group Code.

Comment: @AdamSchneider I suggest you go and try it first. Maybe it is right what you need, if not,  please let me know.

Comment: sorry for the delay. Server went down and I had to wait to test it. I am getting a Object reference not set to an instance. Not quite sure why.

Comment: @AdamSchneider It is up to you to debug now :)